Partial trace of a $n \times n$ square matrix
I would like to create a function to compute the partial of a general matrix.
I came across to the following code for a 4x4 matrix:
ρ = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k, l}, {m, n, o, p}};
ρp = ArrayReshape[ρ, {2, 2, 2, 2}]


My understanding is that ArrayReshape writes the original matrix in terms of 2x2 subsystems.
So the single element of ρp is ρp[[i,j,k,l]]. Now if I contract on the indices 1 and 3 (i,k) I obtain one subspace; and if I contract on the indices 2 and 4 (j,l) I obtain the other subspace.
ρa=TensorContract[ρp, {2, 4}] // MatrixForm
ρb=TensorContract[ρp, {1, 3}] // MatrixForm

But if I want to generalize this to any initial nxn square matrix, how should I proceed?
Let's say I have:
ρ = Array[Subscript[a, #1, #2] &, {8, 8}];


Hello! This is an interesting question. When you say “general (square) matrix”, can you, please, clarify whether you will also be considering a general number of subsystems? If so, presumably you know the ordering of them? This can surely be done with mathematica, as such functionality exists in the Wolfram Quantum Framework. Here, however, I am curious if you are trying to construct something for an arbitrary number of subsystems, or if you will know this in advance?

Hi Ca Trevillian, yes indeed. My goal is to make a function for an arbitrary number of subsystems. I have a very practical problem in mind. Assume that in the course of a chemical reaction, a system AB formed by, let's say, nA nuclear spins undergoes a certain process. I can model the Hamiltonian governing this process, the basis set and the density matrix rho_AB.  Then the AB system separates into A and B. Let's assume I know the dimensionality of A and B somehow. 1stproblem is to determine rho_A and rho_B for example. 2nd is to model more than 2 subsystems.

Please have a look at Section 2.4.3 (pages 36/37) of my book, where this is done in general for mixed states in In[245] and pure states in In[251].

Hi Roman, that was really helpful! Thank you so much!
